# Открытие меню по клику

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я делаю генератор формы. И возник вопрос. У меня есть кнопка которая добавляет input. У этой input есть кнопка с настройками. Когда я нажимаю на нею все нормально, но когда я добавляю еще один input, при нажатии на кнопку открывается настройки не 2ой input, а 1ой. Почему? Помогите пожалуйста.

```js
function addInput() {
 var code = document.querySelector('.code');
 var block = document.getElementById('add-form');
 var posInput = document.getElementById('pos-input');
 var input = document.createElement('input');
 var titleInput = document.createElement('span');
 var edit = document.createElement('button');
 var div = document.createElement('div');
 var changeInput = document.createElement('input');
 var label = document.createElement('label');
 var changeTitle = document.createElement('button');
 var avrBlock = document.createElement('div');
 var editBlock = document.createElement('div');
 input.id = "input";
 input.type = "text";
 titleInput.className = "title-input";
 titleInput.innerHTML = "Имя";
 edit.className = "edit";
 div.className = "block-btn";
 changeInput.id = "change-input";
 changeInput.type = "text";
 label.innerHTML = "Заголовок поля:";
 changeTitle.id = "change-title";
 changeTitle.innerHTML = "Поменять заголовок";
 avrBlock.className = "avrage-block";
 editBlock.className = "edit-block";
 changeTitle.onclick = function() {
  var changeInput = document.getElementById('change-input').value;
  var codeResult = document.getElementById('input-title-name');
var titleInput = document.querySelector('.title-input');
codeResult.innerHTML = changeInput;
titleInput.innerHTML = changeInput;
 }
 avrBlock.appendChild(titleInput);
 avrBlock.appendChild(div);
 avrBlock.appendChild(input);
 avrBlock.appendChild(edit);
 avrBlock.appendChild(label);
 avrBlock.appendChild(changeInput);
 avrBlock.appendChild(changeTitle);
 avrBlock.appendChild(editBlock);
 div.appendChild(input);
 div.appendChild(edit);
 editBlock.appendChild(label);
 editBlock.appendChild(changeInput);
 editBlock.appendChild(changeTitle);
 posInput.appendChild(avrBlock);
 block.appendChild(posInput);
 edit.onclick = function() {
  var dropDown = document.querySelector(".edit-block"); 
    if (dropDown.currentStyle) {
        var displayStyle = dropDown.currentStyle.display;
    } else if (window.getComputedStyle) {
        var displayStyle = window.getComputedStyle(dropDown, null).getPropertyValue("display");
    }

    if (displayStyle == "none") {
      dropDown.style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
      dropDown.style.display = "none";
    }
 }
  code.innerHTML += 
 " &lt;span class='title-input'&gt;" + "<span id='input-title-name'>Имя</span>" + "&lt;/span&gt;&lt;input id='input' type='text'&gt;" + '<br>';
}
function  increaseHeight() {
 var block = document.getElementById('add-form');
 block.style.height = "auto";
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz');
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0

 }
 #container {
 float: left;
 width: 40%;
}

#wrap {
 background-color: #c9c9c9;
height: 100vh;
}
#add-button-container {
 display: inline-grid;
 margin-top: 2%;
}
#add-form {
 background-color: #4C4C4C;
 width: 50%;
 height: 300px;
 border-radius: 4px;
}
#add-form-container {
 display: flow-root;
}
#add-form-block {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 margin-top: 5%;
}
#input {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 0.25em;
width: 88%;
  margin-bottom: 0.6em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #BABABA;
}
label {
 color: white;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 2%;
 font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.15em;
}
#pos-input {
margin: 5% 0 0 5%;
}
#input-textarea {
 margin-bottom: 1em;
 display: block;
}
#input-submit {
 cursor: pointer;
}
.title-input {
 font-size: 1.2em;
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
 text-align: left;
}

#result {
 display: flex;

justify-content: center;
}
.block-btn {
 display: ruby;
}
.edit::after {
   content:"\f14b";
   font-family: "FontAwesome";
   font-size: 2em;
   color: white;
}
.edit {
    background: none;
margin-left: 2%;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
}
#change-input {
margin-right: 2%;
padding: 0.25em;
margin-bottom: 0.6em;
border-radius: 3px;
border: 1px solid #BABABA;
width: 30%;
}
#change-title {
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
border-radius:4px;
padding-left:5px;
padding-right:5px;
padding-top:3px;
padding-bottom:3px;
color:#ffffff;
background-color:#cc6666;
outline:none;
border:none;
cursor:pointer;
display:inline-block;
}

#change-title:hover {
color:#ffffff;
background-color:#d41e1e;
} 
.edit-block {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Генераторы CSS | Rapprogtrain</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="description" content="rapprogtrain-это сайт по изучению программирования">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:400,700" rel="stylesheet">  
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
<div id="container">
<div id="wrap">
 <div class="title">
  <span>Добавить поле</span>
 </div>
 <div id="add-button-container">
<button id="add-input" onclick=" addInput(); increaseHeight();">Добавить input</button>
</div>
  <div class="codes-wrapper">
    <div id="title-res-block2">
      <h3 class="third">CSS Код</h3>
    <button class="clipboard" data-clipboard-target="#codes">Копировать код</button></div>
    <div class="codes" id="codes">
      <p class="line1">&lt;div id='add-form'&gt;</p>
      <p class="line2">&lt;div id='pos-input'&gt;</p>
      <p class="code"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 
</div>

<div id="add-form-container">
<div id="add-form-block">
<div id="add-form">
 <div id="pos-input">
 </div>
 </div>

 </div>
</div>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Одинаковые `id`:

```
input.id = "input";
...
changeInput.id = "change-input";
...
changeTitle.id = "change-title";
```

Поиск по повторяющемуся `id` с использованием `document.getElementById` вернет первый элемент с таким `id`, найденный на странице. То же самое произойдет и с вызовом `document.querySelector`.

> надо на class поменять?

Нет. Надо понимать, как работает Ваш код. В обработчиках событий Вы должны сделать что-то, что определит контекст, ограниченный одним (текущим) из добавленных блоков. Например,

```
//changeInput.id = "change-input";
...
changeTitle.onclick = function() {
  // нужный changeInput здесь уже виден (он снаружи), благодаря замыканию
  //var changeInput = document.getElementById('change-input').value;
  var codeResult = document.getElementById('input-title-name');
  var titleInput = document.querySelector('.title-input');
  codeResult.innerHTML = changeInput.value;
  titleInput.innerHTML = changeInput.value;
}
```

Comment: надо на class поменять?

Comment: этот способ не помог